# what is this error and how do I prevent this? The bucket expression values are not comparable and no comparator specified

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

Im using jasperReports with dynamicReports and I want to build a crosstab report. so far I have figured out that this error happens when I add columns that are numeric to rowGroups or columnGroups. this is what I get and I don't know why and I don't know how to solve this.

The error is:

```
The bucket expression values are not comparable and no comparator specified
```

My code is:

```
    CrosstabValues crosstabValues = report.getCrosstab().getCrosstabValues();
    Collection<CrosstabRowGroupBuilder> rowGroup = generateRowGroup(crosstabValues);
    Collection<CrosstabColumnGroupBuilder> columnGroup = generateColumnGroup(crosstabValues);
    Collection<CrosstabMeasureBuilder> measures = generateMeasures(crosstabValues);

    CrosstabBuilder crosstab = ctab.crosstab();

    for(CrosstabRowGroupBuilder row : rowGroup)
        crosstab.addRowGroup(row);
    for(CrosstabColumnGroupBuilder columnGroupBuilder : columnGroup)
        crosstab.addColumnGroup(columnGroupBuilder);
    for(CrosstabMeasureBuilder measure : measures)
        crosstab.addMeasure(measure);

    crosstab.headerCell(cmp.text(crosstabValues.getHeader())
    .setStyle(getCrosstabHeaderCellStyle(report.getTemplate().getReportTemplateValues())));
```

Comment: Please show some code; while some people can guess what happens, without a context no appropriate answer can be given

Comment: ok Ill do this but code will be confusing and no help

Comment: @user2304200 `so far I have figured out that this error happens` - What error?

Comment: @AlexK the next line is the error bro:

Comment: The bucket expression values are not comparable and no comparator specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was the class I was giving to this method:

```
CrosstabRowGroupBuilder cTabRow = ctab.rowGroup(column.getName()
, getColumnTypeClass(column));
```

i was using Number class for all numeric data. the funny thing is that it worked for measures but it did not work for rowGroup or columnGroup. that is why I got confused.

now with Integer.Class or Long.Class  it works good.

Answer (score 0):

Crosstab must know **in which order** display rowHeader or columnHeader. And crosstab must know **in which cell** of crosstab **put measure**. It is possible only if crosstab is able **compare** rowGroup (and ColumnGroup) values.

Classes which used in rowGroup and columnGroup must `implements Comparable` interface